# Foreach loop with cookies

Tags: php, cookies

I got several cookies that are built like this

```
Parkplatz['1']
Parkplatz['2']
Parkplatz['3']
```

Now i want all cookies with name "Parkplatz" to do a database-query and find the entry with the corresponding Uid, which i try to do like this (i am using extbase, but normal PHP would be working also):

```
$carid = $this->request->getArgument('car_id');
setcookie('Parkplatz[' . $carid . ']', '' . $carid . '', time() + (10 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60));

foreach($_COOKIE['Parkplatz'] as $cookies){
                    $cars = $this->carRepository->findByUid($cookies);
                    $this->view->assign('cars', $cars);
                };
```

This works, but only with the first cookie set with name "Parkplatz". Any ideas?

Comment: you assign cookies array is only one time ,`setcookie('Parkplatz[' . $carid . ']` this will get only one variable

Comment: Have you been successful with the solution below :-) ?

Answer (score 0):

I think, in your loop you are confusing if you have one cookie or a set of cookies.

Your variable `$cookies` is in fact one single cookie. So in the loop assume the `Parkplatz[1]` comes first, then the `$cars` will be found, and they are assigned to `'cars'` in the view. But then, the next loop will overwrite your last assignment for `'cars'` in the view.

To solve this, you need a possibility in your view to add several car-lists. Finally, this could look like this:

```
$viewCounter = 1;
foreach($_COOKIE['Parkplatz'] as $oneCookie){
   $cars = $this->carRepository->findByUid($oneCookie);
   $this->view->assign('car_' . $viewCounter, $cars);
   $viewCounter++;
}
```

Of course this needs some preparation in the template and it might be too static a solution.

Or, collect all car-lists, like this:

```
$allCars = array();

foreach($_COOKIE['Parkplatz'] as $oneCookie){
    $cars = $this->carRepository->findByUid($oneCookie);
    $allCars[] = $cars;
}

$this->view->assign('cars', $allCars);
```

I cannot decide what suits better to your final solution, but I hope this will help you to find the way.

Comment: By the way, there is no need for semicolon after foreach loop with brackets in that specific situation :-) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315459/semicolon-after-closing-curly-bracket-in-php