# Regex letters are not allowed when they should be?

Tags: php, regex

My and my group are trying to create a simple PHP code editor that also executes the code without the use of a library.

We know the risks that come with eval(), but since it's all running on a local server it shouldn't be a problem.

The Regex part is definitely the problem since we have no clue how that works and because it's copied from the internet.

What we are trying to do using Regex is to limit the input to certain words/characters/numbers etc. The problem is that it will fail when trying the input contains words like "Echo"

```html
<textarea id="area" cols="70" rows="30"></textarea>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>

<script>
$('#submit').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var info = $('#area').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'pages/assignments/response.php',
        data: {
            area: info
        },
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

```php
<?php
    if (!empty($_POST['area'])) {
        runEval($_POST['area']);
    };

    function runEval($data)
    {
        $characters = '[a-zA-Z0-9]*';
        $functions = '';
        $operators = '[\w-><$(){}|_+=":;!&*%$]';
        $regexp = '/^((' . $characters . '|' . $functions . '\s*\((?1)+\)|\((?1)+\))(?:' . $operators . '(?2))?)+/';

        if (preg_match($regexp, $data)) {
            eval('$result = ' . $data . ';');
            echo $result;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: "it keeps spitting out POST errors" — Quote the specific error messages. Don't vaguely describe them.

Comment: My bad, Edited the post.

Comment: What are causing said POST errors? What are you typing in the textarea that is causing it to break?

Comment: Also why are you using eval here? It does not need to be used...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2687730/how-can-i-make-php-display-the-error-instead-of-giving-me-500-internal-server-er

Comment: When i literally type something like:
While,if,echo

It spits out a Post 500 error.

Comment: @Erdss4 — The OP is trying to execute user input as PHP source code. They explain that in the first couple of paragraphs of the question.

Comment: @Quentin We enabled that but since the server hasn't restarted it's not enabled and since we are using an external host we are unable to restart the server by ourselves.

Comment: there is a Symfony module I recently learnt of which seems better to use than Eval - see my post here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52315387/evaluate-string-as-condition-php

Comment: your if statement has a semicolon on closing } ?

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs There are no syntax errors.

Comment: @EyesReye it won't throw any - but it's pointless - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315459/semicolon-after-closing-curly-bracket-in-php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the code you copied was initially used for mathematical or string operations, because it assigns a value to a variable (`eval('$result = ' . $data . ';')`).

Try removing `$result =` and the `echo` statement and see if it works.

From the docs:

> The code must not be wrapped in opening and closing PHP tags, i.e.
>   'echo "Hi!";' must be passed instead of ''. It is
>   still possible to leave and re-enter PHP mode though using the
>   appropriate PHP tags, e.g. 'echo "In PHP mode!"; ?>In HTML mode!
>
> Apart from that the passed code must be valid PHP. This includes that
>   all statements must be properly terminated using a semicolon. 'echo
>   "Hi!"' for example will cause a parse error, whereas 'echo "Hi!";'
>   will work.
>
> A return statement will immediately terminate the evaluation of the
>   code.
>
> The code will be executed in the scope of the code calling eval().
>   Thus any variables defined or changed in the eval() call will remain
>   visible after it terminates.

http://php.net/manual/ro/function.eval.php

Btw, note that as said in the docs eval() is very dangerous because it allows to execute **any kind** of valid php code on the server.

See:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/179375/how-eval-in-php-can-be-dangerous-in-web-applications-security